# Sending messages to and from an `asyncio` WebSocket server to an `asyncio` TCP client

Tags: python, websocket, tcp, python-asyncio

I have the following architecture in mind:

[image]

What I need from this is:

1. The WebSocket server and TCP clients must be fault tolerant in the sense that downed connections between them and the external applications must not cause the other parts to go down. For example, if TCP server 1 goes down, TCP client 1 should handle this without affecting the WebSocket server or TCP client 2.
2. The WebSocket server and TCP clients should be able to communicate via some sort of message passing since each one of them should contain their own state. What this messaging is (queues, method calls, etc.), I do not know.

I am comfortable with the idea of `asyncio` and have some understanding of how coroutines run on the event loop. What I am struggling with is how to provide separation between the WebSocket server and TCP clients. In most examples of `asyncio`, everything is bundled into a single `asyncio` function and `asyncio.gather` is called at the end. To me, this couples the individual responsibilities, and I do not understand how to expand these `asyncio` examples to solve (1) and (2).

---

What would help me is a simple example of a WebSocket server sending messages back and forth to a TCP client, both being implemented using `asyncio`. The WebSocket server should use the [`websockets` package](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html). The TCP client should use [`asyncio` streams](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html).

Some example code expanded from the documentation examples:

```py
import asyncio
from websockets.server import serve

async def send_message_to_tcp_client(queue, message):
    queue.put_nowait(message)
    return queue.get()

async def receive_websocket_message(websocket, queue):
    # This also should handle application state. For example,
    # a message may transition a state machine to a different
    # state which would then potentially trigger new messages
    # to the TCP client(s).
    async for message in websocket:
        response = await send_message_to_tcp_client(queue, message)
        await websocket.send(response)

async def websocket_server():
    # I don't know if this queue passing as argument works
    async with serve(receive_websocket_message, "localhost", 8765, queue=queue):
        await asyncio.Future()  # run forever

async def main():
    # Create queue to pass messages back and forth
    q = queue.Queue()

    await asyncio.gather(
        websocket_server(q),
        tcp_client(q)
    )

async def tcp_client(queue):
    reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection(
        '127.0.0.1', 8888)

    # I really need this loop to also handle some state
    # that represents state of the TCP server it is talking
    # to.
    while True:
        message = await queue.get()
        writer.write(message.encode())
        await writer.drain()

        data = await reader.read(100)
        queue.put_nowait(data)

    writer.close()
    await writer.wait_closed()

asyncio.run(main())
```

What this code doesn't demonstrate (assuming it's even a valid solution) is fault tolerance. How should disconnects and errors in the WebSocket and TCP communication with the external clients and servers, respectively, be handled? It's also confusing how to ensure synchronization between the WebSocket and TCP client(s). What should be started first?